# a-frame - Lost control of cone radiusBottom and radiusTop

Tags: aframe

I'm making a simple submarine object in a-frame: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/periodic-best-lantern?path=index.html%3A4%3A41 but am unable to set the radiusBottom and radiusTop of the stern part, id="backCone".  What have I missed?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/1.1.0/primitives/a-cone.html#sidebar) - You'll see that the primitive mappings are a bit different from the component attributes. In this case:

- `radius-bottom` is mapped to `geometry.radiusBottom`
- `radius-top` is mapped to `geometry.radiusTop`

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-cone color="tomato" position="-1 1 -2" radius-bottom="1" radius-top="0.5"></a-cone>
  <a-cone color="tomato" position="1 1 -2" radius-bottom="0.1" radius-top="0.5"></a-cone>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: Many thanks @Piotr Adam Milewski .  I'd missed that difference.  All good now.  Thank you.

Comment: @MzEdd If you don't have further questions feel free to mark the anwser :)